# What's With The Integral $\int\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}\, \mathrm d\theta$?

Tags: calculus, integration

A student randomly asked me to compute

$$\int\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}\, \mathrm d\theta.$$

I was unable to do so, as were several other instructors.  I typed the integral into Wolfram and it says that it is an elliptic integral of type 2.  I am not familiar with elliptic integrals and I don't have any idea why this student asked me to do this since we are not even doing derivatives yet.  Is this integral important?  Does it have a closed form answer?

Comment: I guess since $\int \cos 2 \theta \ d \theta$ is easy compute...it would be a reasonable assumption that $\int \sqrt{\cos 2 \theta} \ d \theta$ is easy to compute.

Comment: Did you try the Wikipedia article?  This integral might appear if you were interested in computing the circumference of a certain ellipse.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: I checked out the article and if one were to integrate from 0 to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ one would get the circumference of the ellipse of eccentricity $\sqrt{2}$.  This is not one of the special cases given in the article.

Comment: @Joe: the indefinite integral (the incomplete as opposed to the complete elliptic integral) measures part, rather than all, of the circumference.

Comment: "A student randomly asked me to compute" , what was happening at the time? randomly asking someone to compute an integral that turns out to be elliptic is quite remarkable! What other questions does this student ask?

Comment: Stupid question: If $\cos{2\theta}$ can be negative, how is the square root (thus the indefinite integral) evaluated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The elliptic integral of the second kind crops up since

$$\int\sqrt{\cos\;2\theta}\;\mathrm d\theta=\int\sqrt{1-2\sin^2\theta}\;\mathrm d\theta=E(\theta|2)+C$$

where $E(\phi|m)=\int_0^\phi \sqrt{1-m\sin^2\theta}\;\mathrm d\theta$ is the incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind.

All well and good, but traditionally one transforms elliptic integrals such that the parameter $m$ is within the interval $[0,1]$ (corresponding to the fact that ellipses have their eccentricity in the interval $(0,1)$). Using [certain transformations](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7#ii), one now has

$$E(\theta|2)=\sqrt{2}E\left(\arcsin(\sqrt{2}\sin\;\theta)|\frac12\right)-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}F\left(\arcsin(\sqrt{2}\sin\;\theta)|\frac12\right)$$

where $F(\phi|m)=\int_0^\phi\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\sqrt{1-m\sin^2\theta}}$ is the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind, which is probably what you want.